# erro arquivo facesProduces

Tags: jsf-2.2, spring-security, cdi

está dando erro

> Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409:
>   Ambiguous dependencies for type HttpServletRequest with qualifiers
>   @Default   at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private
>   com.oliveira.pedidovenda.controller.LoginBean.request   at
>   com.oliveira.pedidovenda.controller.LoginBean.request(LoginBean.java:0)
>   Possible dependencies: 
>     - WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%C:\Users\Adriano\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PedidoVenda\target\PedidoVenda-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes%HttpServletRequest,
>     - Producer Method [HttpServletRequest] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces
>   @RequestScoped public
>   com.oliveira.pedidovenda.util.jsf.FacesProducer.getHttpServletRequest()]

Answer (score 0):

basta ler um pouco seu log de errro pra ver o problema: "Ambiguous dependencies for type HttpServletRequest with qualifiers". Não expert em jsf, mas sei que este erro ocorre quando você está injetando dependência mas o CDI não consegue encontrar o objeto, ou classe específica que você pretende injetar. Você pode resolver isso com Qualificadores do java, funciona como anotação.
vou exemplificar com o meu produtor de DAO.
Qualificador

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE,ElementType.PARAMETER,ElementType.FIELD})
public @interface DAOPadrao {

}
```

Faça importações necessárias, agora, na classe de produção:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class DAOProducer implements Serializable {

@Produces
@RequestScoped
@DAOPadrao
public SuperDAO superDAO() {
    return new SuperDAO();
}
}
```

Basicamente é so você criar sua anotação qualificadora e anotar o método produtor com ela.